# К какому типу односотавных относится предложение :

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

*Орленок, орленок ,взлети выше солнца и степи с высот огляди?* Думаю определенно-личное.

Comment: Опечатка, пробел не по месту, отсутствие знака препинания: какого типа этот вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно, в чём сомнение? Лицо определено - ты. Сказуемое  выражено глаголом 2 лица.

Answer (score 1):

Если глагол стоит в форме повелительного наклонения, то такие односоставные предложения относят к определенно-личным (в речевом контакте участвуют два ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫХ лица: говорящий и его собеседник)

Глаголы в повелите. наклонении не имеют лица (при разборе 2-е лицо не указывается), только время: взлети - влетите.