# Нужна ли запятая перед повторяющимся союзом "и" в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, повторяющийся-союз, смысловое-единство

> Узнай, на самом ли деле он — жестокий плейбой, как написали в
> газете, и просто закрой глаза(,) и думай об Англии.

Интуитивно не хочется ставить эту запятую. Можно ли считать, что в данном случае два последних однородных сказуемых в выражении *закрой глаза и думай об Англии* образуют тесное смысловое единство, означая *потерпи*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Узнай [это] и просто закрой глаза и думай.*

Интуиция и чувство языка правильно подсказывают: запятая перед вторым союзом ***и*** не нужна.

> **8.** Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом ***и***, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом ***и*** с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится.

Источник: [справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101).

Comment: Александр, у меня вопрос по грамматике. Может, тесное единство нужно определять для определенно-личных предложений?

Comment: @Sharon  Ну не зна-а-ю... А какая разница какие глаголы или другие однородные? "Он узнал об этом и просто закрыл глаза и начал думать". (Можно, конечно, перед первым ***и*** запятую поставить или даже тире.) В любом случае в вопросном предложении действительно не хочется ставить запятую, так как союз соединяет пару.

Comment: Запятая не нужна однозначно, но нужно объяснить это  для односоставных предложений.   Или доказать, что их можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым.

Comment: @Sharon  Честно, не понимаю, зачем доказывать. Неужели глаголы в повелительном наклонении или односоставные предложения не могут быть однородными? Об этом наверняка бы написали в том же справочнике, чтоб люди отделяли их от "обычных" однородных.

Comment: А как вам вот эта тема, там тоже повелит. наклонение.  Две знайки  дают разные ответы: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415480/К-какому-типу-односотавных-относится-предложение

Comment: Я думаю, здесь расчлененность первого предложения и двух других, причем эти два связаны частицей "просто".

Comment: Посмотрел. Только не понял, что там объясняет нашу тему. И вот это: "Глаголы в повелите. наклонении не имеют лица, только время: взлети - влетите". Почему не имеют, если "(ты) взлети, (вы) взлетите"? А вот времени у повелит. наклонения как раз нет.

Comment: Вы видите, что это односоставные предложения (повелит. накл.)? У нас тоже односоставные предложения, а не однородные сказуемые.

Comment: Ну и ладно, пусть предложения, хотя я всё равно не понимаю эти лингвистические заморочки: что мешает этим глаголам быть сказуемыми? *Ты (что сделай) узнай, закрой, подумай*.

Comment: Ну ладно, ничево. Только это предложения, а не члены предложения)) // КСТАТИ.  Категория лица форм повелительного наклонения имеет три грамматических значения – первого, второго и третьего лица, которые указывают на того, кто, с точки зрения говорящего, должен выполнить действие.  Ты сделай.  Пусть она сделает. Давай  вместе сделаем.

Comment: То есть глаголы в повелит. накл. не могут быть сказуемыми? Так?

Comment: Могут. У нас там три простых предложения в составе сложного.

Comment: Ужасно заковыристо придумано! :) Делать им нечего, этим лингвистам (шутка).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень интересно было прочитать и ваше с @Sharon обсуждение вопроса в комментариях, всегда узнаю тут что-то новое!

Comment: @Sharon, вы упомянули, что два последних простых предложения (если я правильно поняла из ваших объяснений, это не одно простое предложение с несколькими сказуемыми, как я думала) связаны частицей _просто_. Если бы этой частицы не было, то запятую всё равно не нужно было бы ставить? Сохраняется ли расчленённость первого предложения и двух остальных, исходя из их смысла? Или сохраняется ли тесная смысловая связь двух последних глаголов без частицы, надеюсь, вы поймёте, о чём я пытаюсь спросить.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос. Частица "просто"  — это самый НАГЛЯДНЫЙ признак слитности двух предложений, Розенталь, пункт 2(5): 5) В некоторых случаях общим элементом может быть частица (ограничительная, усилительная, выделительная): В воздухе тишина; только поскрипывает на берегу кузнечик да где-то робко мурлыкает орличка (Ч.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Есть и другие ПРИЗНАКИ:  Первое предложение (узнай) это вообще БСП,  два других предложения связаны по смыслу (с закрытыми глазами думай об Англии).  Нет перечислительной интонации.  Кстати, в грамматике сказано, что односоставные предложения с общим элементом приравниваются к ОДНОРОДНЫМ членам.

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за объяснения, всё понятно!